# how to use session variable in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How to get `Session["UserId"]` value in Linq Query

```
 var result = (from c in db.UserMaster
                      where c.UserID == Session["vUSerID"].ToString() 
                      select C ).ToList();
```

but when i execute it gives me error as follows

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Please guide me how to works with `ToString()`

Comment: Try Convert.tostring()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619350/how-to-query-data-within-a-session-variable-using-linq

Answer (score 4):

You need to materialize the value *before* you send it off to be translated to SQL:

```
var userId = Session["vUSerID"].ToString();
var result = (from c in db.UserMaster
                  where c.UserID == userId 
                  select C ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try bringing entity into memory first, and then apply the condition to get the filtered result, although not recommended because of the potential performance issue.

```
var result = db.UserMaster.Select(x => x).ToList().Where(x => x.UserId == Session["vUSerID"].ToString()).ToList();
```